# Export Android contact deails in csv format

Tags: android, json

hi i'm new to android n want to know how i can export the android contacts in a csv format.

As i need to transfer the file to web server and then need to store it in a centralized database(MySQL) vCard is less preferable...

or else may sound silly but can i convert it in JSON?

Your replay will really mean a lot to me thanks..

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701774/1289716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this answer: [Android contacts extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction)

Looks like VCard is the easiest choice, as there's an API for it.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. can u suggest me the best vCard API for java as my requirement is to transfer the contacts to centralized database (Mysql) and again take backup from that database to android device.. so m not sure about which format would be easier to work with i.e CSV,vCard or JSON i need to transfer the contacts using web services.. any eg. would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Just follow the link and check out some of the code and links to the Android Developer Site. I'm not really a vCard expert, so I can't help you out much there.

Don't forget to accept my answer if you feel like it's a good one! :D